# why code does not start? there is no error code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-form-quiz

This is my script.  I click "play" but there is no result in form.

1. import Question From sheet B
2. import Question From Sheet D
3. Sheet G mean 90, 70, 50, 30, 10 and if G > 80.
4. Question is 23. and I want to breakpage 10 question - breakpage  10 question - breakpage -10 question
   THis is T/F quiz.
   T : true , O
   F : false, X

```
 function learn3() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;

  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var form = FormApp.openByUrl('MY URL');

  var num = 3;
  var ten = activeSheet.getRange(5, 2).getValue();
  ten = ten - 1;
  var one = activeSheet.getRange(6, 2).getValue();
  for (var i = 0; i < ten; i++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      var B = activeSheet.getRange(num, 2).getValue();
      var D = activeSheet.getRange(num, 4).getValue();
      var G = activeSheet.getRange(num, 7).getValue();
      var H = activeSheet.getRange(num, 8).getValue();
      if (G > 80) {
        Logger.log('code1');
        var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
        item.setTitle(B);
        item.setChoices([
          item.createChoice('(O)', true),
          item.createChoice('(X)', false),
        ]);

        item.setFeedbackForCorrect(
          FormApp.createFeedback()
            .setText(D)
            .build()
        );
        item.setFeedbackForIncorrect(
          FormApp.createFeedback()
            .setText(D)
            .build()
        );
      } else if (G > 60) {
        var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
        item.setTitle(B);
        item.setChoices([
          item.createChoice('(O)', true),
          item.createChoice('(X)', false),
        ]);
      } else if (G > 40) {
        var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
        item.setTitle(B);
        item.setChoices([
          item.createChoice('(O)', false),
          item.createChoice('(X)', true),
        ]);

        item.setFeedbackForCorrect(
          FormApp.createFeedback()
            .setText(D)
            .build()
        );
        item.setFeedbackForIncorrect(
          FormApp.createFeedback()
            .setText(D)
            .build()
        );
      } else if (G > 20) {
        Logger.log('code4');

        var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
        item.setTitle(B);
        item.setChoices([
          item.createChoice('(O)', false),
          item.createChoice('(X)', true),
        ]);
      } else {
        Logger.log('code5');
      }
      num = num + 1;
      var page = form.addPageBreakItem();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are there two nested loops?

Comment: if ten is 1, I want to loop 10, ten is 2 loop 20

Comment: `ten = ten - 1;` if `ten` is 1, `ten-1`=0. `i < ten`=> `0<0`=false. Loop won't start

Comment: Could you please share a sanitized copy of the spreadsheet and the form you are working on?